# Change values in object without changing parent object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a object with some (cards) values and I would like have another object which has values converted (cards by name) by another function.

```
cardsHand = [
{ value: "1", suit: "C" },
{ value: "13", suit: "C" },
{ value: "12", suit: "C" },
{ value: "11", suit: "C" },
{ value: "10", suit: "C" },
];

function sortCards(cardsHand) {
//SORT VALUES
let sortedCardsByValue = [];
sortedCardsByValue = cardsHand.sort(
(currCardA, currCardB) => currCardA.value - currCardB.value);

//CHANGE VALUES
let convertedCards = cardsHand;
convertedCards.forEach((element) => {
if (+element.value === 1) element.value = `A`;
if (+element.value === 11) element.value = `J`;
if (+element.value === 12) element.value = `Q`;
if (+element.value === 13) element.value = `K`;
});

return {
convertedCards,
sortedCardsByValue,
};
}

console.log(sortCards(cardsHand).convertedCards);
console.log(sortCards(cardsHand).sortedCardsByValue);
```

So I would like to achive object sortedCardsByValue:

```
[
{ value: '1', suit: 'C' },
{ value: '10', suit: 'C' },
{ value: '11', suit: 'C' },
{ value: '12', suit: 'C' },
{ value: '13', suit: 'C' }
]`
```

and object convertedCards (which is sorted like parent but with changed names for example 1->A; 11->J):

```
[
{ value: 'A', suit: 'C' },
{ value: '10', suit: 'C' },
{ value: 'J', suit: 'C' },
{ value: 'Q', suit: 'C' },
{ value: 'K', suit: 'C' }
]
```

But my code from the beginning creates both objects the same.

I have made some functions to solve this bug. I've tried map methos, replace method, forEach, Object.values().

Comment: why not add a new property? Why use the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `let convertedCards = cardsHand;` means - create a new variable with a reference to exactly the same object

This `let sortedCardsByValue = [];` does nothing because you assign a different array in the next line

Sort works in place so you don't have to assign to a new variable

```js
const cardsHand = [{
    value: "1",
    suit: "C"
  },
  {
    value: "13",
    suit: "C"
  },
  {
    value: "12",
    suit: "C"
  },
  {
    value: "11",
    suit: "C"
  },
  {
    value: "10",
    suit: "C"
  },
];

function sortCards(cardsHand) {
  cardsHand.sort(
    (currCardA, currCardB) => currCardA.value - currCardB.value);

  let convertedCards = cardsHand.map(obj => ({ ...obj
  }));
  convertedCards.forEach((element) => {
    if (+element.value === 1) element.value = `A`;
    if (+element.value === 11) element.value = `J`;
    if (+element.value === 12) element.value = `Q`;
    if (+element.value === 13) element.value = `K`;
  });

  return {
    convertedCards,
    sortedCardsByValue: cardsHand,
  };
}

const {
  convertedCards,
  sortedCardsByValue,
} = sortCards(cardsHand)

console.log(convertedCards);
console.log(sortedCardsByValue);
```

Comment: So `let convertedCards = cardsHand.map(obj => ({ ...obj}))` creates a copy of parent object?

Comment: [The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Okey, I have forgotten that map() method creates a new array. Thanks for answer.